# Is it possible for a Slack bot to listen to user @-mention events?

Tags: slack, slack-api

In Slack, users are pinged when they are [@-mentioned](https://slack.com/help/articles/205240127-Use-mentions-in-Slack) in a channel. Is it possible for a bot or app to receive an event when a user is tagged this way? It doesn't seem to be on the [Event Types API](https://api.slack.com/events).

Answer (score 1):

The [`app_mention` event](https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention) is meant to handle just this scenario.

Any time a message references your app by its bot username (e.g. `@myBot`), your app will receive this event along with metadata like the user ID who wrote the message, the text of the message, timestamp, and channel ID.

Comment: If I've understood the question (and I am looking for this too), this is not answering it. The question is not if the app is mentioned. The question is "can my app get an event if user A mentions user B?".